# titletoc: problem with "left" parameter (not working for LOF)

Tags: vertical-alignment, titletoc

I am having trouble with changing the style of the LOF using `titletoc`. Everything works fine but the **left** parameter (i.e. the first parameter in the square brackets containing a length measure) of the `\titlecontents{figure}` command does not have any effect (it seems to be 0pt regardless of the value I provide). However, it works for `chapter`, `section`, and `subsection`. Is this a known bug or am I too stupid?

The misalignmentis shown in the picture:

[image: BUUUG]

I would like to have *Figure* aligned with *Section*.

Please find a MWE below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{titletoc}


\contentsmargin{0pc}

% Section
\titlecontents{section}
[2.25pc]
{}
{\hspace*{-.75pc}\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentslabel}\hspace*{.75pc}}
{}
{\hspace{.5pc}\raisebox{.3ex}{$\scriptstyle\cdot$}\hspace{.5pc}\thecontentspage}

% Figures
\titlecontents{figure}
[2.25pc]
{\raggedright}
{\contentslabel{2.25pc}}
{}
{\hspace{.5pc}\raisebox{.3ex}{$\scriptstyle\cdot$}\hspace{.5pc}\thecontentspage}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\section{Section}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please complete your code to a full but minimal document. We can't compile it, as it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work fine for me if I delete the \raggedright command. Then I just used the same code you used for Section and it aligns just like you wanted.

```
\titlecontents{figure}
[2.25pc]
{}
{\hspace*{-.75pc}\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentslabel}\hspace*{.75pc}}
{}
{\hspace{.5pc}\raisebox{.3ex}{$\scriptstyle\cdot$}\hspace{.5pc}\thecontentspage}
```

But then the numbers don't align, but you can fix it by changing the hspace distances in the last line.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. However, I still don't understand what \raggedright messed up; I moved it to the end of the second parameter, which seems to work.

Comment: You're welcome. I am not sure what you wanted to do with raggedright, but the place where you put it in is used for global formatting for the whole entry and you basically told the entry to go to the left side.